# Why the last rule matching in my lex file, when I have better rules?

Tags: regex, bison, yacc, lex, bisonc++

I have a `lex` file, with my rules, such as:

```
PROGRAM           return Parser::PROGRAM;
PROGRAM_END       return Parser::PROGRAM_END;
VARIABLES:        return Parser::VARIABLES;
INSTRUCTIONS:     return Parser::INSTRUCTIONS; 
SKIP              return Parser::SKIP;
.           {
                std::cerr << lineno() << ": ERROR." << std::endl;
                exit(1);
            }
```

and when I try to use the fully compiled (with the `yacc` file and etc) version then on a test file only this, last rule is used, even if the test file is correct.

For example this is a test file for these rules:

```
PROGRAM fst
INSTRUCTIONS:
    SKIP
PROGRAM_END
```

For this file I only got: `1: ERROR`.

Why is this, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Either your input doesn't contain `<`, `<=` or `>`, you're wrong about only the last rule being is used, or there's something else going on in your real code that isn't visible in the excerpts you posted. It's impossible to say without seeing a [mre].

Comment: @sepp2k I updated my question with an example and the necessary rules for this example.

Comment: How do you know that the `PROGRAM` rule doesn't run in that example? If you add a print statement to that rule, I'm sure that you'll see its output. Anyway, you probably shouldn't exit the program on unknown characters if you want it to still do something (other than exitting with an error message) for input that contains unknown characters. I'd also suggest to print the offending input in the `.`-rule.

Comment: @sepp2k I know it, because the `yacc` file should print each rule which is catched. If I print with `YYText()` then also nothing: `1: ERROR: `

Comment: @sepp2k and also if I remove this `.` rule then the `yacc` will print everything, but, the rule not will be correct and will allow bad files too.

Comment: When I make your code compilable and then add a print statement to the `PROGRAM` line, I see the output of the print statement (followed by the error message afterwards and the program exiting). I find it hard to believe that you wouldn't.

Comment: And regarding yacc not doing anything: That's not surprising if the lexer exits the program while the parser is still parsing. Even if you have an action with a print statement directly after the program token, the parser might very well ask for another token before executing that action. So if the lexer exits at that point, the parser won't get to do anything.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, I got this too, but, if I go forward then the `fst` or `INSTRUCTIONS` and so on didn't appear as an output. And also, the `yacc` file should catch this, and print it, but it doesn't do this.

Comment: You're calling `exit` in the `.` rule. So after the `.` rule executes, nothing else will happen. If you don't want that, don't call `exit`.

Comment: @sepp2k Ok, I got it, but why exits the lexer, when it has rules which match for other things? I have rule for each part of this test file. The `fst` should be catched by `({CHAR}|{UNDERSCORE})` rule and `CHAR [a-zA-Z]` `UNDERSCORE "_"` macros.

Comment: You'll probably find out if you print the offending character in the `.` rule. I can't tell you which rules are missing in your real code because I haven't seen your real code, but I can tell you that in your example the first unknown character will be the space between `PRORGAM` and `fst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, it is almost certainly the case that `PROGRAM` is begin recognised as a token and passed to the parser. In almost all cases, however, the parser will immediately request another token, and the next character in the input sequence is a space, which is matched by the last rule. That rule prints an error message and calls `exit()`, terminating the application. (That's not generally a good idea, but I suppose this is just a test program.) So that's all the output you'll get.

If you specify the `-d` command-line argument when you invoke (f)lex, then a debugging scanner will be generated which reports the progress of the scanner as it works. That's a very easy way to see what is going on in your scanner. Bison also has a debugging mode, as explained in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Debugging). These tools are very simple to use, and come highly recommended.

Here, for example, is a quick test rig:

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
class Parser {
  public:
    enum Token {
      PROGRAM = 257,
      PROGRAM_END, VARIABLES, INSTRUCTIONS, SKIP
    };
};
%}
%option batch noyywrap yylineno c++
%%
PROGRAM           return Parser::PROGRAM;
PROGRAM_END       return Parser::PROGRAM_END;
VARIABLES:        return Parser::VARIABLES;
INSTRUCTIONS:     return Parser::INSTRUCTIONS; 
SKIP              return Parser::SKIP;
.                 {
                    std::cerr << lineno() << ": ERROR." << std::endl;
                    exit(1);
                  }
%%
int main() {
  yyFlexLexer lexer{};
  lexer.set_debug(1);
  while(lexer.yylex() != 0) { }
  return 0;
}
```

And a sample run:

```
$ g++ lex.yy.cc && ./a.out<<<"PROGRAM fst"
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--accepting rule at line 14("PROGRAM")
--accepting rule at line 19(" ")
1: ERROR.
```

which makes it clear that the scanner did first produce the `PROGRAM` token, before exiting on the space character.